# JasperReports How to do pagination in Excel

Tags: excel, printing, jasper-reports

I am trying to put page numbers/breaks at the bottom of each page and columns headers at the top, so when printed from Excel all pages are numbered and headed. It should not be such a big deal, right? But unfortunately it is, no matter what approach I tried I just cannot get the page number and page break at the bottom of the pages - they are anywhere else but at the bottom. I put "Page X of Y" in the Page Footer section, the Ignore Pagination is NOT checked, and when I generate the report I have Page X or Y after every 4 lines of data. I extended the page Height to 3-4 times of the standard height of Letter Landscape format, and that changed the footer to be printed after 18-20 lines of data - this is not a reliable way of adjusting it.
Also I tried putting the Page Break with Print When expression set to print it every 20 lines, but that still it is not accurate, since on the first page I have less lines of data because of the Report Title - if I adjust it to be correct on the 1st page - it will print it somewhere in the middle on the next pages.
Am I missing something obvious in the design how to put footer with page #s? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue with help of [**net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.height**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.height) parameter.

I set the report's height and ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.height*** report's property with the same value.

The sample:

```xml
<jasperReport ... pageWidth="595" pageHeight="800" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    ...
    <parameter name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.height" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[800]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    ...
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="433" y="0" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="513" y="0" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

The result (preview in MS Excel):

[image: Result in MS Excel]

Comment: It did not change anything. BTW where you specify the height value it is looking for a String, so it should be declared like: <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["800"]]></defaultValueExpression>
Which Jasper Reports version are you running? I upgraded to 3.7.5 in order to use this property but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I tried the same and could not resolve it. If there hadn't been a drastic change in between (and I delete this answer instantly if one in provided) then you are lost.

I'm sorry.

Comment: @sstoynov please state what you mean by the 'newest' (because in 6 Months that wont be the same anymore). And no, I didn't.